# PHP array group by category

Tags: php

I have a list of stores and they can have multiple categories.

Today i display each store multiple times, one line with only one category.

How can i group the stores, creating an array of their categories, so the store is displayed only one time and have their multiple categories ?

This is my attempt:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    array_push(
        $stores,
        [
            "id"=> $row["id"],
            "name"=> $row["nome"],
            "categories"=> array([
                "name"=> $row["categories"]
                //how can i have an array of categories
            ])
        ]
    );
}
```

This is how i display the json result:

```
{
    id: 74,
    name: "First Store",
    categories: [
        {
            name: "Clothes"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Second Store",
    categories: [
        {
            name: "Food"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Second Store",
    categories: [
        {
            name: "Toys"
        }
    ]
},
```

---

This is how i need to show the Json:

```
{
    id: 74,
    name: "First Store",
    categories: [
        {
            name: "Clothes"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Second Store",
    categories: [
        {
            name: "Food"
        },
        {
            name: "Toys"
        }
    ]
},
```

---

In my attempt i try inside the while to create the categories but have a php warning: `end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

```
if( isset($stores) ) {
    if(  end($stores['id']) != $row["id"] )  {
            array_push($category_array, $row["categories"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: More I thought about my answer below, is there a reason why you can't edit your SQL query to group the distinct categories by store id to get the category array etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this when processing your returned `MySQL` rows to `json_encode`: https://3v4l.org/d4Wf2

This will place the stores in 1 temp `$storeTracker array` with the store id as the `array key` (this assumes store id is a constant in each record you're getting back and is always the same). From here you can then check if the `array key` (store id) already exists, and if so, continue to add categories to the store if the category doesn't already exist. After doing this, you can then parse to `json_encode` to create a valid `JSON` object to return. Granted there may be a more eloquent way to achieve this, but this showcases the `array` manipulation and whatnot to try and group data for your case.

```
<?php

// Data coming from MySQL Database
$rowData = [];
$rowData[] = ['id' => 74, 'name' => 'First Store', 'categories' => 'Food'];
$rowData[] = ['id' => 74, 'name' => 'First Store', 'categories' => 'DVDs'];

$rowData[] = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Second Store', 'categories' => 'Food'];
$rowData[] = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Second Store', 'categories' => 'Toys'];
$rowData[] = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Second Store', 'categories' => 'Toys'];
$rowData[] = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Second Store', 'categories' => 'Clothing'];

$rowData[] = ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Third Store', 'categories' => 'Toys'];
$rowData[] = ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Third Store', 'categories' => 'Clothing'];
$rowData[] = ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Third Store', 'categories' => 'Clothing'];

/**
 * Check if store category name already added to store record
 */
function categoryExistsAlready($categories, $category) {
    foreach($categories as $key => $catArr) {
        if(strtolower($catArr['name']) === strtolower($category)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$storeTracker = [];
foreach($rowData as $key => $storeData) {

    $storeCategory = $storeData['categories'];
    $storeId = $storeData['id'];

    // If store exists, add category to categories array
    if (array_key_exists($storeId, $storeTracker)) {
        if (!categoryExistsAlready($storeTracker[$storeId]['categories'], $storeCategory)) {
            $storeTracker[$storeId]['categories'][] = ['name' => $storeCategory];
        }
        continue;
    }

    // Update store categories to be array with category
    $storeData['categories'] = [];
    $storeData['categories'][] = ['name' => $storeCategory];

    // Add store data to overall tracking array
    $storeTracker[$storeId] = $storeData;
}

// Format JSON response
$jsonReturn = '[';
$i = count($storeTracker);
foreach($storeTracker as $storeId => $storeData) {
    $i--;
    $jsonReturn .= json_encode($storeData);
    // Determine last comma separating objects
    if ($i > 0) {
        $jsonReturn .= ',';
    }
}
$jsonReturn .= ']';

echo $jsonReturn;
```

Will give you this valid `JSON` https://jsonlint.com/:

```
[{
    "id": 74,
    "name": "First Store",
    "categories": [{
        "name": "Food"
    }, {
        "name": "DVDs"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Second Store",
    "categories": [{
        "name": "Food"
    }, {
        "name": "Toys"
    }, {
        "name": "Clothing"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Third Store",
    "categories": [{
        "name": "Toys"
    }, {
        "name": "Clothing"
    }]
}]
```